# Not able to run nodejs project on google app engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I have just started google app engine with nodejs. I have created a local project that works fine on my machine. And If I hit

http://localhost:7000/services/user/getuser

it returns a json object.

I have deployed the same project on google app engine using

```
gcloud app deploy
```

Now when I hit

http://help-coin.appspot.com/services/user/getuser

it is showing

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

I have checked the logs on server

```
Load controllers from path '/app/app/services' non recursive.

--------make-runnable-output--------

undefined

------------------------------------

Up and running on port 7000

Loading controller 'UserService.js'.
```

No error on the server side. What is this issue? Am I missing something?

Here is the project that I have deployed https://github.com/ermarkar/nodejs-typescript-sample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app **must** listen to 8080, not 7000 or any else port.

See [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#listen_to_port_8080).

> Listening to port 8080
>
> The App Engine front end will route incoming requests to the appropriate module on port 8080. You must be sure that your application code is listening on 8080.

Comment: is there any way to change port to work this working on 7000?

Comment: @SunilGarg I don't think so. What's the problem with 8080 ?